# How to model 2D array board in UML: associations vs attributes

Tags: class, multidimensional-array, uml, composition, class-diagram

I have to model a board of elements in UML, something similar to a Chess game, but here **the dimension of the board is variable**. My problem is when modelling the board. I am modelling it as a two dimensional array of pieces (there is a piece that represents the empty cell).

Here is an example image of what I have:

[image]

- **Is this correct?**

It seems to me that expressing the relation between Board and Piece both with the piece[][] attribute and with the association is **redundant**, but otherwise I can't figure out how to represent a two dimensional array just with associations.

- **Is there a way to express a 2D array of elements just with association and multiplicity?**

EDIT:

- The board size depends of the values in the "rows" and "columns" attributes. **Is it Ok to express it as a derived attribute?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to express a 2D array of elements just with association and multiplicity?

no, the multiplicity only indicates the number of elements, not how the collection is structured (a matrix/2D-array in your case).

note it is exactly the same using the notation with an attribute in its compartment in a class, so `[8][8]`as you probably wanted to do (you also missing the multiplicity inside the `[]`) is not part of the standard.

In [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) §9.5.4 page 113 :
`<property> ::= [<visibility>] [‘/’] <name> [‘:’ <prop-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘=’ <default>] [‘{‘ <prop-modifier > [‘,’ <prop-modifier >]* ’}’]<property> ::= [<visibility>] [‘/’] <name> [‘:’ <prop-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘=’ <default>] [‘{‘ <prop-modifier > [‘,’ <prop-modifier >]* ’}’]`

So if you want to follow the standard you have to use `[64]` whatever you use an association or an attribute.

> It seems to me that expressing the relation between Board and Piece both with the piece[][] attribute and with the association is redundant

In your diagram, forgetting the problem concerning the multiplicity and the fact there is no multiplicity for the association meaning 1, it is not possible to know if the association corresponds to your attribute because the name of the property/*memberEnd* is missing. Anyway to show both the attribute and the association corresponding to the same property is legal ... even that does not solves your problem.

---

**After you edit**

If the number of row and columns is not statically known the number of pieces is also variable => the multiplicity to use is `[0..*]` (or the shortcut `[*]`) or `[1..*]` depending if you can have or not no square.

For me to use a derived attribute is at minimum useless, but worst hide the fact you *really* have a collection of piece.

---

**How to say a matrix is used**

The simplest way to indicate you have a matrix of *row* x *column* in your diagram is to add a note, of course that way is just informational and cannot be enough in case you also want to generate code but that also depends on the tool you use. So for instance :

[image]

An other way can be to define a template class for your array (for the notation of the binding see page 26 of [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1)) :

[image]

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks a lot for your answer. It answer a lot of my questions! The problem is that I don't really know the size of the board. It depends on a row and column attribute in the board class. I edited the question to include that. Sorry, I tried to simplify the problem for the question so much that i missed that.

Comment: thanks a lot! Just to clarify one thing before marking your answer as accepted: then, If I understood it correctly there is no way in UML to specify how the collection is structured? I can't show that the board is a 2D-array of elements in any way?

Comment: @NilSuria I edited my answer, of course there are other ways including out of the norm but accepted in tools including mine

Comment: Thanks a lot @bruno. I marked your answer as accepted. The second option seems what I'm looking for, but I will need to research a little bit about Class templates since I don't understand how them work.

Comment: @NilSuria UML template classes are the equivalent of templates in C++ / generic in Java.

Answer (score 4):

To [Bruno's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64941913/3723423) comprehensive and excellent answer,  I'd nevertheless would like to add that there is an opportunity to improve the model, abstracting it from the 2D array and expressing in an implementation neutral way what you want to achieve, by using a [qualifier](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#qualifier):

[image]

This says in an implementation neutral way, that you can map the board with some coordinates to a piece.  You could further refine this model with a constraint on the value of the coordinates.  The advantage is that you're not bound to a 2D array.  You could as well use a hash-map or a dictionary using a pair of coordinates to get the piece.

Comment: thank you for that complement, I thought about it but did not mention it because I do not support this notation in my tool ... yes this is a scandalous reason ^^